# how can I change log file path and name in symfony which uses sfLogger class

Tags: php, logging, symfony1

I am using symfony 1.x framework and usually all the logs are put under repective applications /log/_dev/prod.log

But I want to change the log file name and path and where can I configure it.

I have got a liitle more info [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_0/en/16-Application-Management-Tools#)

but it is not given here about the file path and name config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution for this.

```
$log = new sfFileLogger();
$log->initialize(array ('file' => '<path with file name>',));
$log->log($message, $level);
```

Thanks